# When Creating Multiple Flows with a Routing agent how do I store user variables?

Tags: global-variables, google-cloud-dataflow

As an example, assuming that the agents are going to be specialized for individual departments, so Lets say I have a Receptionist Agent, a Technical Support Agent and A Sales Agent.

Now the Receptionist Agent has a flow that will determine the Customers Name and Account Number as well as The fact that they need to obtain Technical Support. Then transfers the customer to the technical Support Agent.

When the customer Arrives at the beginning of the flow for Technical Support, the Receptionist already identified the customer and their account number, so I want the Technical Support Agent to be able to access that information from their Flow.

I see that there are page variables and session variables for the specific Flow that the user is in, But I am looking for a User variable that will stick with the user between flows from the Receptionist to the Support that then transfers them to Sales flow to add on a product.

A more global variable, I can not seem to find them can anyone assist?

Thank you

Comment: sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you clarify?

Comment: So I am creating dialogflow cx on google.com and connecting to voice using Twilio. 

The Caller dials a toll free number and is routed to a flow that is the receptionist bot. The bot does a reverse lookup of the calling phone number and finds it is a pre-existing customer and asks, is this Mr Jones? and the caller confirms.. So the receptionist has identified Mr. Jones with customer id 123456.  Mr Jones says he needs  to speak to someone in support. and the Bot confirms and says please stand by Then transfers the caller to another Flow that is the support bot, (See next Comment)

Comment: The support flow is a bot that is managed by the support department. Prior to transfering the caller the receptionist gathered the name and customer id and stored the values in a session variable. when the caller is passed to the support flow the session variables for the receptionist bot go away and are no longer accessible. I want to tie variables to the caller that are accessible across flows (ie between Reception and support)